# Is there any way to add arabic text in as3?

Tags: actionscript-3, textfield, arabic

I want to add Arabic text using AS3. But the problem I am facing is that once I assign text to textfield, the text gets reversed. Is there any way by which I can get this thing done. If there is any SWC that is required, please send me the link to that too.

Comment: Use the [**edit**](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58097886/edit) button. Show us some testable example of this Arabic text. Show us your current result vs expected result (paste text or use a free screen grabber software).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `TLFTextField`

```
var tlf:TLFTextField = new TLFTextField();
tlf.defaultTextFormat = new TextFormat( "arialArabic" );
tlf.antiAliasType = AntiAliasType.ADVANCED;
tlf.direction = flashx.textLayout.formats.Direction.RTL;

tlf.text = "هلو ورد!";
```

Or if you need to use the standard `TextField` then you'll need to look into using a library like the one below to correct the text :

https://github.com/SaffronCode/UnicodeRTL

eg:

```
textField.text = UnicodeStatic.convert("هلو ورد!");
```